# How to use pyspark dataframe columns as arguments for transformation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am brand new to spark and concurrent processing, so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

I have a bunch of files across a few GCS buckets that I need to convert from ORC to CSV and store them in a separate bucket under specific file names unique to each original file.

My idea was to create a spark dataframe and use the column names as arguments. My dataframe stored as variable `sdf` resembles this:

| read_path | write_path |
| --- | --- |
| gs://src/0/file0 | gs://dest/0/file0 |
| gs://src/0/file1 | gs://dest/0/file1 |
| gs://src/1/file0 | gs://dest/1/file0 |
| gs://src/1/file1 | gs://dest/1/file1 |
| gs://src/2/file0 | gs://dest/2/file0 |
| gs://src/2/file1 | gs://dest/2/file1 |

I tried this, but it failed with SPARK-5063:
`sdf.foreach(lambda row: spark.read.orc(row.read_path).write.option('header', 'true').option('sep','|').csv(row.write_path))`

From what I can make out, the error is due to attempting to nest a transformation inside an action. What would be an elegant way to do this?